# How did the Huygens probe use EM waves to measure wind speeds on Titan?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, waves, space, doppler-effect, satellites

In the Wikipedia's article on Huygens spacecraft, it was mentioned that one of the experiments was to measure the wind speeds on Titan by [Doppler wind experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens_(spacecraft)#Doppler_Wind_Experiment_.28DWE.29). To quote the exact lines, it was

> This instrument was also used to measure the wind speed in Titan's atmosphere by measuring the Doppler shift in the carrier signal.

EM waves speed is independent of the medium's speed. So I wonder, how could wind speeds affect the carrier waves's frequency?

Answer (score 1):

The speed of an electromagnetic wave is indeed independent of the speed of both the source and the receiver. However, this does not mean that the relative motion between the source and the receiver has no effect on the wave's properties.

The effect that is being used is called the [Doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect), and it is the fact that the received frequency of a wave will be shifted up or down depending on whether the source is moving towards or away from the receiver. This is similar to the change in pitch in ambulance sirens as they pass by; the details are slightly different for sound and for light but the effect is nevertheless very much present.

The detection of wind speeds simply assumes that the Huygens probe's lateral motion will be at speeds comparable to the wind, which is a fairly reasonable assumption.

Comment: But you haven't explained how wind speeds are measured by Doppler effect. Can you update your answer with details explaining that part too?

Comment: @karthikeyan See response in post.

Comment: @karthikeyan: the experiment measured the lateral speed of the Huygens probe. Because the probe is dangling from a  parachute being swept along by the wind it's assumed that the lateral speed of the Huygen's probe is roughtly the same as the wind speed. So this gives us an indirect measurement of wind speed.